# Addition of items to the "NEW" button in eclipse toolbar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I'm developing a custom project plugin wizard.

Currently the custom project wizard option shows up when I press "CTRL+N"

Or when I navigate from toolbar "New -> (drop down list) -> other.

Instead I want my selection to my newprojectwizard in the dropdown list that is generated for the "New" button on toolbar.

We see that the new button on toolbar has the following format.

A list of perspective controlled options.

Dotted lines and "Example"
Dotted line and "other"

I want to put my custom project wizard either in the section along with "example" or "other"

Any help or code snippet highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to add to the top level new menu. The `newWizardShortcut` adds the shortcut.

For example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension targetID="org.eclipse.pde.ui.PDEPerspective">
     <newWizardShortcut id="org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui.wizard"/>
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

Comment: Okay i feel i got the issue,

I dont have a custom perspective for my plugin. So how do i add it to the file-new dropdown of whatever perspective the eclipse is in ?

Comment: You have to add this for each perspective you want to modify, you can use this for existing perspectives as well as new ones.

Comment: So for Java perspective, what should be the modification i should do to the above snippet ? ?

Comment: The main Java perspective id is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective`. The `newWizardShortcut` id is whatever your wizard id is.

Comment: yes what you have said is correct, but for some reason it just doesnt get added to that list in Java pespective also . I dont know why.

Comment: It is sometimes necessary to reset perspectives with 'Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective'